# Nextcloud <-(SAML)->Keycloak as identity provider issues

Tags: owncloud, nextcloud

I’ve followed this blog on configuring Newcloud as a service provider of Keycloak (as identity provider) using SAML based SSO. I am using Newcloud AMI image here: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06ZZXYKWY

Things seem to work, in that I redirect the keycloak sign in, but after I authenticate with keycloak, I get redirected to a newcloud page that just says

“Account not provisioned.
Your account is not provisioned, access to this service is thus not possible.”

There are various “patches” on the internet, but they are old, and I have checked and the php file paths that people modify are not even the same on my system.

Does anyone know how to debug this “Account not provisioned” issue? I call it an issue because I know the account exists and I was able to authenticate using the keycloak UI.